# How to fetch current location in appdelegate using swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, mkmapview, currentlocation

Hi am developing a app using swift i want to fetch current location of the user when app launches so i written my code in app delegate i have include all the functions and methods i.e.. added and imported frameworks core location and also updated plist but i cant able to fetch current location

code in my app delegate:

```
import UIKit

 import CoreLocation


import MapKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var window: UIWindow?
  var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?


  private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    determineMyCurrentLocation()

    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    if (configureError != nil){
        print("We have an error:\(configureError)")
    }
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "331294109111-o54tgj4kf824pbb1q6f4tvfq215is0lt.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}



func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let latestLocation = locations.last

    let latitude = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation!.coordinate.latitude)
    let longitude = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

    print("Latitude: \(latitude)")
    print("Longitude: \(longitude)")
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil){
      // let googleName = user.profile.name
       let locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = currentCoordinate!
        let latitude = locValue.latitude
        let longitude = locValue.longitude
        let userID = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
        print("users id = \(userID)")
          print("userlatitude = \(latitude)")
        print("userlongitude\(longitude)")
        print(user.userID)
        let profilePicURL = user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(200).absoluteString
        print(profilePicURL)
        let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let centerViewController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthViewController") as! FourthViewController
            centerViewController.userid = socialMessage as String
        let leftViewController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController
        leftViewController.ProName = user.profile.name
        leftViewController.proImage = profilePicURL as String
        let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
        self.centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)
        self.centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        self.centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        self.window!.rootViewController = self.centerContainer
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    else{
        print("looks we got signin error:\(error)")
        }
}
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                                                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}
```

And also i want to use current lat and long in the method:

```
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
    here i want to use lat and long
 }
```

Comment: have you added permission in info plist?

Comment: yes i have added permission in plist

Comment: is it asks for permissions too after installing and running 1st time ?

Comment: no i have already added and worked in other view controller but i cant fetch in app delegate

Comment: @user7333282 Mark Breakpoint to your didUpdateLocations method @ AppDelegate check whether this delegate is calling or not. When it call then call your SignIn function from that delegate.

Comment: not even printing current location i.e latitude and longitude...i think func did update location is not working..@dheeraj

Comment: if i use breakpoint and execute it shows fatal error at  let locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = currentCoordinate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Just call setupLocationManager() in didFinishLaunchingWithOption.

    func setupLocationManager(){
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

        }

    // Below method will provide you current location.
     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            if currentLocation == nil {
                currentLocation = locations.last
                locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                let locationValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

                print("locations = \(locationValue)")

                locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

    // Below Mehtod will print error if not able to update location.
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print("Error")
        }
```

Comment: yes its working..now how can i use that lat and long in func signin:gid sign in method

Comment: var currentLocation:CLLocation?

Comment: yeah thats working just help me to use that lat and long in other functions

Comment: Declare one global var with type CLLocationCoordinate2D, now you can get (CLLocationCoordinate2D : lat, long) from didUpdateLocation method and store that values in your global variable and then use that globlal variables values in your  func signin:gid sign in method.

Answer (score 3):

By the following code you can get name of location and it's longitude and latitude

```
extension AppDelegate :  CLLocationManagerDelegate
{

    func geocode(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark?, Error?) -> ())  {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)) { completion($0?.first, $1) }
    }

    // Below Mehtod will print error if not able to update location.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error Location")
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        //Access the last object from locations to get perfect current location
        if let location = locations.last {

            let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude)

            geocode(latitude: myLocation.latitude, longitude: myLocation.longitude) { placemark, error in
                guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else { return }
                // you should always update your UI in the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //  update UI here
                    print("address1:", placemark.thoroughfare ?? "")
                    print("address2:", placemark.subThoroughfare ?? "")
                    print("city:",     placemark.locality ?? "")
                    print("state:",    placemark.administrativeArea ?? "")
                    print("zip code:", placemark.postalCode ?? "")
                    print("country:",  placemark.country ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```