# TableView sort by distance from current location (parsing locations from JSON)

Tags: swift, xcode, sorting, distance, cllocationmanager

Within xCode, I am trying to sort objects within a TableView so that they appear in order of how close they are to the user. I have seen this question asked, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it into my project as I am parsing the locations through a JSON file.

What do I need to do to calculate the distance between the user's location and the location of each location object? And how can I then sort the objects within the TableView in ascending order?

Here is the Location.swift model:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

var currentLocation:CLLocation?

class Location: NSObject {
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var type: String = ""
    var location: String = ""
    var image: String = ""
    var activity: String = ""
    var rating: String = ""
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    var distance: Double {
        get {
            return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude).distance(from: currentLocation!)
        }
    }

    init(locationInfo:[String:Any]) {
        self.id = locationInfo["id"] as! String
        self.name = locationInfo["name"] as! String
        self.type = locationInfo["type"] as! String
        self.location = locationInfo["location"] as! String
        self.image = locationInfo["image"] as! String
        self.activity = locationInfo["activity"] as! String
        self.latitude = locationInfo["latitude"] as! Double
        self.longitude = locationInfo["longitude"] as! Double
}

    public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        return coordinate
        }
    }

}
```

Here are the relevant parts from LocationTableViewController.swift:

```
class LocationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var locations = [Location]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationService: LocationService = LocationService()
        locations = locationService.readLocation()
        locations.sort { $0.distance < $1.distance }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.nameLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row].name
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: locations[indexPath.row].image)
        cell.locationLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row].location
        cell.typeLabel.text = locations[indexPath.row].type
        return cell
    }
}
```

This is what I have implemented in AppDelegate to capture the user's location:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    private var currentCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var currentLocation:CLLocation?

    static var locations: Array<Location> = Array()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Location Manager
        func setupLocationManager() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    // Location Manager
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if currentLocation == nil {
            currentLocation = locations.last
            locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            let locationValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
            print("locations = \(locationValue)")
            locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Defined one more property in your Location model called `distance`. which is distance from user's current location.

```
var distance: Double {
        get {
            return CLLocation(latitude: latitude , longitude: longitude).distance(from: userLocation)
        }
    }
```

This returns distance in `CLLocationDistance`, but you can use it as Double, because it makes easy while sort.

Now you can sort `locations` in ascending array like this and Reload data

```
var locations = [Location]()

locations.sort { $0.distance < $1.distance  }

self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is probably a noob error, but I get an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'userLocation'." Is this because I need to define the userLocation? Where should I do this?

Comment: @joshlorschy You have to save User location in global or in some shared instance. it's depend on you

Comment: Can I do it in the Location.swift model? Or should it be in AppDelegate?

Comment: @joshlorschy if you do it with Location model, you have to pass it on all object. So it is not efficient.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how I can do it then? Sorry, I am very new to coding!

Comment: @joshlorschy In AppDelegate, Using Location manager get and save the current location of user and after that you can use it in whole application.

Comment: @joshlorschy Is that you implemented?. Please inform me if you have any problem

Comment: I have implemented it in AppDelegate using the answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464215/how-to-fetch-current-location-in-appdelegate-using-swift, but I still get an error (I did change 'userLocation' to 'currentLocation')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151686/discussion-between-joshlorschy-and-jaydeep).